# Como fazer 3 SelectOneMenu aninhados?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou criando uma página que tem que ter 3 `SelectOneMenu` do primefaces.
No primeiro carregarei um centro (da universidade), o segundo carregará um edital e o terceiro carregaria as disciplinas desse edital.

O primeiro `SelectOneMenu` funciona, quando troco de opção ele carrega apenas os editais daquela opção. Mas quando eu troco a opção do segundo `SelectOneMenu` ele já nem chama o método. Porque ele não tá chamando o método? Qual o erro? Seguem os códigos:

**deferirInscricoes.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="formInscricoes">

    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectCentro" value="#{inscricaoBean.centroSelecionado}" converter = "centroConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="- Selecione um Centro -" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{inscricaoBean.listaCentros}" var="centro" itemValue="#{centro}" itemLabel="#{centro.nome}"/>
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{inscricaoBean.carregaEditais}" update="selectEdital" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectEdital" value="#{inscricaoBean.editalSelecionado}" converter = "editalConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="- Selecione um Edital -" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{inscricaoBean.listaEditaisPorCentro}" var="edital" itemValue="#{edital}" itemLabel="#{edital.titulo}"/>
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{inscricaoBean.carregaDisciplinas}" update="selectDisciplinas" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectDisciplinas" value="#{inscricaoBean.disciplinaSelecionada}" converter = "disciplinaConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="- Selecione uma Disciplina -" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="- Teste -" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{inscricaoBean.listaDisciplinaPorEdital}" var="disciplina" itemValue="#{disciplina}" itemLabel="#{disciplina.nome}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>  
 <h:form>
```

**inscricaoBean.java**

```
private List<Centro> listaCentros;
private List<Edital> listaEditaisPorCentro;
private List<Disciplina> listaDisciplinaPorEdital;
CentroDAO centroDAO = new CentroDAO();
EditalDAO editalDAO = new EditalDAO();
DisciplinaDAO disciplinaDAO = new DisciplinaDAO();
private Centro centroSelecionado;
private Edital editalSelecionado;
private Disciplina disciplinaSelecionada;

// Todos os getters e setters acima foram criado no padrão.

public void carregaEditais() {
    System.out.println("Editais carregados.");
    listaEditaisPorCentro = editalDAO.getListaEdital(centroSelecionado);
}

public void carregaDisciplinas() {
    System.out.println("Disciplinas carregadas.");
    listaDisciplinaPorEdital = disciplinasDAO.getListaDisciplinaPorEdital(edital);
}
```

}

**CentroConverter.java**

```
@FacesConverter("centroConverter")
public class centroConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                CentroDAO centroDAO = new CentroDAO();
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(value);
                Centro centro = centroDAO.getCentro(id);
                return centro;

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Problema no centroConverter.!");
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro de conversão", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            Centro c = new Centro();
            c = (Centro) object;
            return ""+c.getIdCentro();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

**EditalConverter.java**

```
@FacesConverter("editalConverter")
public class editalConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                EditalDAO editalDAO = new EditalDAO();
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(value);
                Edital edital = editalDAO.getEdital(id);
                return edital;

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Problema no editalConverter.!");
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro de conversão", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            Edital e = new  Edital();
            e = (Edital) object;
            return ""+e.getIdEdital();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

**DisciplinaConverter.java**

```
@FacesConverter("disciplinaConverter")
public class disciplinaConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                DisciplinaDAO disciplinaDAO = new DisciplinaDAO();
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(value);
                Disciplina disciplina = disciplinaDAO.getDisciplina(id);
                return disciplina;

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Problema no disciplinaConverter.!");
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro de conversão", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            Disciplina d = new Disciplina();
            d = (Disciplina) object;
            return ""+d.getIdDisciplina();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

O primeiro método ele chama, carrega a lista. Mas o segundo não. Coloquei um *print* só pra testar, mas o método não está sendo chamado.

Comment: Já tentou ao invés de `valueChangeListener` usar `<p:ajax>`?

Comment: coloque <p:ajax> que funciona

Comment: @Luídne coloquei o p ajax, mas não funciona do mesmo jeito. Ele não chama o método de jeito nenhum.

Comment: @PedroLaini também.

Answer (score 1):

Sei que o post é antigo, mas talvez alguém esteja passando por problema parecido é segue então uma dica muito importante:

Eu estava com problema parecido e quebrei a cabeça fui em vários post na net e a o problema estava na verdade, na relação entre **Model X converter x selectOneMenu**, para que ele funcione corretamente precisa que os "Models" tenha os métodos **equals() e hascode() implementados**, no caso deste post seria implementar nas classes Centro, Edital e Disciplina.

O Fato de não ter estes métodos implementados, pode gera um erro na fase de validação do JSF impedindo a sequencia normal das fases.

Answer (score 0):

Esse listener `valueChangeListener` só é chamado quando o usuário selecionar uma opção, e você não deu um update no seu segundo select, sendo assim ele não vai carregar as novas informações.

Minha sugestão adicione em seu primeiro select:

```
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="{inscricaoBean.clearEdital}" update="ID_DO_PROX_SELECT" />
```

remova o `valueChangeListener="#{inscricaoBean.clearEdital}"`
e altere seu método:

```
public void clearEdital(){
    listaEditalPorCentro = editalDAO.getListaEdital();
    System.out.println("Centro: "+centroSelecionado);
    System.out.println("Edital: "+listaEditalPorCentro);

}
```

O seu centroSelecionado já vai estar com o novo valor por causa do `process="@this"`

Comment: Fiz da mesma forma que vc falou, ai eu seleciono o primeiro select, ele executa o metodo e atualiza o segundo, quando seleciono o segundo ele n chama o metodo e nem armazena o valor no editalSelecionado. Mas o update ele funciona.

Comment: Você fez a mesma coisa pro segundo?

Comment: Sim sim, fiz exatamente a mesma coisa, copiei e colei e modifiquei o que precisava ser modificado.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi corretamente, ao selecionar a primeira opção é gerado uma nova lista para o segundo select baseado no que foi selecionado, e assim por adiante?

Comment: É exatamente isso, no segundo select deve ter um metodo que carrega a lista do terceiro (assim como foi feito no primeiro).

Comment: Você pode postar todos os métodos que você esta utilizando? Só pra ver se esta faltando algum detalhe.

Comment: Eu to no celular agora, to esperando um amigo trazer o cabo da internet e posto atualizado. Beleza?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25606/discussion-between-rafael-ferreira-and-joao-neto).